# Refresh imported value from a python module

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project with project with several files
for one I declare one variable as None and then inside a function I update it's value.

**module_1.py**

```
import pandas as pd
df_data = None
def read_files():
    global df_data
    df_data=pd.read_xlsx('dummy.xlsx')
```

**module_2.py**

```
from module_1 import df_data
from module_1 import read_files

read_files()
print(df_data)
# This returns None
```

I thought that being a global variable it would update even after importing because from **module_1.py** file I'm updating its value.
But its none.

I think its because python imports the module initially with the value None, and even if set as global it won't reload the value.

I could do a get function, but is there any other way?

What's the correct way to do this? Make a get function and return the object itself?
Is there any way to refresh variables after importing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: change the `from` import in `module_2`

```py
import module_1
from module_1 import read_files

read_files()
print(module_1.df_data)
```

Explanation: your `from module_1 import df_data` creates a reference in the scope of `module_2` to `df_data` from `module_1`. In your `read_files()` function you replace the value of `df_data` in the global scope of `module_1`, but this (as you figured it out) doesn't change anything in the scope of `module_2`.